# How in laravel get output of mysql console command?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu

On laravel 10 site I need in admin area to show some info on mysql database, which is used in mysql db replication.

When I need to get mysql status I run command under mysql console :

```
SHOW MASTER STATUS \G
```

But with symfony/process library I can get and show output of linux commands, but not a command which I run under mysql console.
I searched in mysql-mariadb section of the documentation :
https://docs.platform.sh/guides/symfony/environment-variables.html?utm_source=symfony-cloud-sign-up&utm_medium=backlink&utm_campaign=Symfony-Cloud-sign-up&utm_content=docs#mysql-mariadb
But I did not find any hints how to get output of the command.

How this can b3e domn? Some other tools ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.35.0",
"symfony/process": "^6.4",
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this using DB facades , handle the result and show in your view

```
//in your route 


Route::get('/admin/mysql-status', 'AdminController@mysqlStatus');


// in your Controller  

$status  = DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW MASTER STATUS'));


return view('admin.mysql_status', ['status' => $status]);



// in your view  

@foreach ($status as $row)
    <p>{{ $row->YourColumnName }}</p>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

You can run a CLI command to connect to MySQL and run the script you wanted:

```
mysql -h yourroot -u youruser -pyourpassword -e "yourscript;"
```

Of course, you will need to replace:

- yourroot
- youruser
- yourpassword
- yourscript

with appropriate values.

Comment: Run a CLI command from laravel ?

Comment: @PetroGromovo why not? Even vanilla PHP allows you to run a CLI command.

Comment: Please example in laravel

Comment: @PetroGromovo this works on any PHP environment, including Laravel: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php and if you prefer to execute it in a more Laravel-specific manner, then this one might suit you: https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html